# How do I check a user input against a pre-defined value when it can be an integer or a word?

Tags: python, while-loop, fizzbuzz

```
import random
lives = 3
while lives > 0:
   print("If the number is divisible by 3, type FIZZ (all caps)")
   print("If the number is divisible by 5, type BUZZ (all caps)")
   print("If the number is divisible by 3 and 5, type FIZZ BUZZ (all caps)")
   print("If the number is none of the above, type the number")
   print("You have three lives and then the game is over")
   print("Try and beat me!")
   for number in range(1,101):
      if number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0:
          correct_answer = "FIZZ BUZZ"
      elif number % 3 == 0:
          correct_answer = "FIZZ"
      elif number % 5 == 0:
          correct_answer = "BUZZ"
      else:
          correct_answer = number
      first_go = random.randint(0,1)
      if first_go == 0:
          computer_go = True
      else:
          computer_go = False
      if computer_go == True:
          print("CPU:", correct_answer)
          computer_go == False
      elif computer_go == False:
          answer = input("Your go:")
          if answer == correct_answer:
              computer_go = True
          else:
              print("Wrong answer!")
              lives - 1
```

I tried to use the if statement 'if answer == correct_answer' but it doesn't seem to be working for values that are neither FIZZ, BUZZ or FIZZ BUZZ. I'm also having trouble regarding the while loop; the message 'wrong answer' is printed, however the while loop does not end after three wrong attempts as it should with lives - 1 resulting in lives becoming 0 and ending the while loop.

Comment: First test if the value is an integer or is a word. in the if statements Such as `if input_variable.isdigit() and ...` or `if input_varible.isalpha() and...`. Although I  should note, I don't see anywhere in your program where you're getting user input.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, the input is in the 28th line.

Comment: You probably need to revise the whole logic. Aside from the live coutner, the program won't stop even if you fail three times in the first 100 tries because of the larger for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
correct_answer = number
```

do

```
correct_answer = str(number)
```

That way you're comparing strings to strings.

You're not changing the value of `lives`.  Do

```
lives = lives - 1
```